# Change Value of specific Entry in JavaScript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, select

I seem to be stuck at a probably idiotic problem but I can't figure it out...

There are classes for a Player, an Army, and a Unit.
The Player object contains several armies, which in turn contain several units.

I add a player like so: `let player1 = new Player()`

I add armies within the player object like: `this.armies.push(new Army())`

I add the units within the army object like: `this.units.push(new Unit(data))` - data being an object, containing the unit's base stats.

This all works fine.

Now – when I try to change a stat of a single warrior unit (for example `player1.armies[0].units[0].hp -= 2`), it also changes the stats of each other warrior unit in all armies of player1.

How can I select a specific warrior unit by index within a specific army of player1?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to the same `units` array from all `Army` objects, but we can't say for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place, even on a holiday weekend. When you post a question (or answer), please *stick around* so you can deal with anything that comes up in the comments.